# Cannot find python in command prompt even after python being installed

Tags: python, command, command-prompt

When I write python in cmd, I get a message `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. But at the same time when I write git, then I do  get the desired result. Does that mean I need to make some changes to the environment variables.

Comment: did You add python to the PATH? (actually an option when installing python). either how there are many tutorials and information about how to add python to the PATH, oh and PATH is an environment variable

Answer (score 1):

You need to add python to the path. Look at [Manually add python to path](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)